# Unable to deploy OpportunityLineItem.Name to production org from sandbox

Tags: deployment

I have what looks like a standard field `OpportunityLineItem.Name` in my sandbox.

When I compare the sandbox with the production org using Gearset, it identifies the field is missing, but won't let me deploy it:

[image]

When I try and create a normal change set, I cannot seem to select it as a field.

1. What is going on?
2. How do I get the field into production?

Comment: +1 for being a Gearset user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a case with Salesforce support, and was told that `OpportunityLineItem.Name` is only available in the sandbox because it is a Winter 21 sandbox preview.

Answer (score 3):

The Name is a standard field on OpportunityLineItem and it will be available by default in the org. You can refer soap api guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm).

The opportunity line item name (known as “Opportunity Product” in the user interface). This read-only field is available in API version 30.0 and later.

The changeset will not have capability to deploy standard objects according to this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HJ3kAAG).

[image]

[image]

I have tried fetching OpportunityLineItem metadata using SFDX, It does not return the Name field.

[image]

These are my findings on deploying Name field.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to update the name and saw the difference in gearset for OpportunityLineItem.Name field between 2 orgs.PFB.

[image]

So it depends upon whats changed  in your field. In case there is no difference between 2 orgs for that field, Gearset does not show the field itself.

Regarding your second option of change set, i also was not able to find this field while creating the changeset.

Comment: Could you confirm if you were able to deploy the std field (name) via gearset?

Comment: Yes, was able to deploy this field through gearset